# javascript fadein/fadeout, fading out img flicks on top in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, fadein, fadeout

I am making this site http://bit.ly/JV5I0Z and

I have a fade-in effect, where the 2nd image (newBg) stands on top of the first one (bgImg) and fades in, then i copy the src from the 2nd to the 1st so now they are both the same image, then set the 2nd's opacity to 0 and repeat whenever the user changes image.

This works fine on opera and chrome, but on firefox the fadein is like too slow, and the fading out img (which doesn't really fade out as i said, just gets overwritten) flicks in the end of the animation, appearing then disappearing.

I am not sure what is causing this, and what could be causing the slow fadein in firefox?

Here is the code handling the fade in thing: http://jsfiddle.net/VbjPc/1/

Any help is appreciated.

edit ------------

I have updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VbjPc/1/ with the code that i use for preloading the images. The new code is at the bottom. I think preloading is working cause nothing happens until the images load and you can tell cause they are like ~500kb so it takes a couple seconds for them to load.

Comment: Your bit.ly link is not working for me.

Comment: Even with the bitly, you should still post the relevant code so that if the link ever breaks, your question is still valuable to our community.

Comment: Correct link:  http://bit.ly/JV5I0Z

Comment: If your images aren't preloaded, that can cause a sort of flickering effect. Not sure if that's what's happening here as I'm in Chrome, but  you should try that as a possibility.

Comment: @jmort253 - I see the same, looks fine in FF after a full cycle, but until the images are loaded it is flashy. Even Chrome is a bit flashy.

Comment: i have updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VbjPc/1/ with the code that i use for preloading the images. the new code is at the bottom

i think preloading is working cause nothing happens until the images load and you can tell cause they are like ~500kb so it takes a couple seconds

Comment: @LeandroZhuzhi - I just now saw your edit. If my answer doesn't answer the question, consider adding your solution as an actual answer to the question and omitting it from the question itself. This helps keep uniformity among questions and answers and makes it easier for other users to identify your solution. Thanks for coming back and following up with your findings!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an image is loaded for the first time in a Web browser, there is a certain degree of latency that is involved when the browser downloads the image.

In general, most websites have a lot of moving parts. When an HTML document is downloaded by the browser, the browser will then start processing all of the elements and events that are represented by the HTML elements in the HTML document.

For instance, CSS begins loading when link tags are encountered. JavaScript is loading for script elements. Other HTML elements are added to the DOM. As this happens, events are triggered that send requests to the server to download these resources.

When an `img` tag is added to the DOM, a request is sent to the server to retrieve the resource identified by the src attribute. Once the image is fully downloaded, it is rendered on the page.

Assuming we're working with images that are appropriate sizes for a Website, when we load an image normally, without effects, we don't really notice the latency because the image is more or less instantly displayed as soon as it's done downloading.

However, when we add in effects, such as fadeIn and fadeOut, the effects of the latency become quite clear. This occurs because the JavaScript events actually start modifying the CSS properties of the img element, even though the actual resource isn't ready.

Thus, the fadeIn and fadeOut events fire as soon as the DOM element is added to the DOM, not when the image is done loading. In other words, The fadeIn or fadeOut actions occur while the image is still being downloaded. This creates a jarring effect, as a partially faded yet unrendered image may suddenly appear and then fade slowly in the rest of the way.

This action is not the smooth, gradual effects we're looking for.

Now, you may notice that this doesn't happen the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, or nth time you load the image. With the image being cached by the browser, the latency is greatly reduced, and the fadeIn/fadeOut effects appear as they should. Smooth and gradual.

The technique I normally use when fading in an image is to first preload it. While there are libraries out there that will preload all of your images for you, here is a very simple, fast technique for preloading an image, before you apply your fadeIn event:

**Place the image in the HTML as a hidden image:**

```
<!-- Hidden by default, but now preloaded for a smooth fadeIn effect -->
<img id="myImage" src="/images/myImage.png" style="display:none" />
```

**Use jQuery to add the hidden image while binding click events:**

If the image is something that will fadeIn after a click event occurs, I've found this technique to be quite helpful:

```
// preload the image while registering the click event
$('<img id="myImage" src="/images/myImage.png" style="display:none" />')
    .append("body");

$('button').click(function() {
    $('#myImage').fadeIn();
});
```

**Use jQuery's load event to preload the image as it's needed:**

It's possible the user may never click the button to show the image; thus, here is a technique to preload the image when it's requested, but still without jarring the user. Should the user decide not to click on the button, the resource will never be requested from the server. Furthermore, since we wait for the image to load before firing the fadeIn event, we also still get the smoothness we're looking for but with a possible, slight delay before the process begins.

```
// preload the image while registering the click event

$('button').click(function() {
    // place img element on page without specifying the src attribute
    $('<img id="myImage" style="display:none" />').append("body");

    // bind a load event to the image element so fadeIn doesn't start until
      // the image is completely downloaded
    $('#myImage').load(function() { 
        $(this).fadeIn();   // fade in the image
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. However, from what i gather this is talking about preloading an image, which already existed in my code, i just had not written it the first time. I did update the jsfiddle code including my preloading code after people suggested that i might not be preloading.

I am not sure if i have something wrong in my preloading script, but it works well on opera and chrome.

Comment: I have copied the site on my local disk and the fade in is still slow. I think it's probably an issue other than preloading. I will keep making some tests and hopefully get more help.

Comment: I just saw your code updates. Is there some reason why you're not using jQuery's fadeIn and fadeOut methods? Both have the ability to pass a callback function, which would help you write a swapImage function in just 3 or 4 lines of code. Is that something you'd consider?

Comment: I'm a newbie in all this, so i'm taking it one thing at a time. In the future sure it might interest me to learn it.

Comment: Take a look at [jQuery fadeIn documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and look at the 2nd parameter, the callback. You can chain together a fadeOut function after an image is done fading in (and you can do the same with fadeOut). Good luck!